# how to show filecount on UI in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

what I am trying to do is to update the file count on UI every time it reads the file. Similarly it is not even showing the total number of files on the UI , the moment user clicks on the ok button of the browseFolder event.Any help would be appreciated. Below Is my Code :

```
private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int fileCount = 0;
            string newFileName1 = "";
            string newFileName2 = "";
            week = textBox2.Text;
            if (week == null || week == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Week cannot be null.");
                return;
            }


            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                int j = 0;
                int totalNoOfFiles = 0;
                DateTime starttime = DateTime.Now;

                string folderPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                string folderName = Path.GetFileName(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath);

                totalNoOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
                lbltotalfiles.Text = Convert.ToString(totalNoOfFiles);
                progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
                progressBar1.Maximum = totalNoOfFiles;

                DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

                foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                    newFileName1 = "Files_with_dates_mismatching_the_respective_week_" + folder.Name + ".txt";
                    newFileName2 = "Files_with_wrong_date_format_" + folder.Name + ".txt";

                    if (File.Exists(folderPath + "/" + newFileName1))
                    {
                        File.Delete(folderPath + "/" + newFileName1);
                    }

                    if (File.Exists(folderPath + "/" + newFileName2))
                    {
                        File.Delete(folderPath + "/" + newFileName2);
                    }

                    FileInfo[] folderFiles = folder.GetFiles();

                    if (folderFiles.Length != 0)
                    {
                        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
                        foreach (var file in folderFiles)
                        {
                            fileCount = ++fileCount;
                            lblFilesRead.Text = Convert.ToString(fileCount);
                            progressBar1.Value = ++j;
                            var task = ReadFile(file.FullName, folderPath, folder.Name, week);
                            tasks.Add(task);
                        }

                        Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
                        DateTime stoptime = DateTime.Now;
                        TimeSpan totaltime = stoptime.Subtract(starttime);
                        label6.Text = Convert.ToString(totaltime);
                        textBox1.Text = folderPath;

                    }
                }
                DialogResult result2 = MessageBox.Show("Read the files successfully.", "Important message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are reading/processing files you are stoping Windows event queue that is responsible for interaction with user/repainting components. You should call from time to time: `Application.DoEvents()` method. It will allow application to process messages like updating label text.

If you want a really good user experience you should use another thread to process files and from that thread use `label.BeginInvoke` method to update labels on your form. Here is good tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke

Answer (score 0):

You could also have look at the `FileSystemWatcher` class. This might be a little easier to maintain in the long run...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher()
        {
            Path =  @"G:\cc\",
        };

        watcher.Created += Watcher_Created;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Watcher_Created(
        object sender, 
        FileSystemEventArgs e
        )
    {
        var folder = new DirectoryInfo(e.FullPath)
            .Parent;

        Console.WriteLine(
            folder?
                .GetFiles()
                .Length
            );
    }
}
```